# change background color of placeholder django cms

Tags: css, django-templates, django-cms

I want user to be able change colors of placeholders.

I try to install djangocms-css-background.
I fallowed these steps https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangocms-css-background/1.0.4

at first i had error : "no module found djangocms-css-background" When i ran python manage migrate.

Somehow i fixed an error. But im stucked with this one

```
djangocms-css-background.CssBackground.cmsplugin_ptr: (fields.E306) The name 'djangocms-css-background_cssbackground' is invalid related_name for field CssBackground.cmsplugin_ptr
    HINT: Related name must be a valid Python identifier or end with a '+'
```

settings.py

```
import os
gettext = lambda s: s
DATA_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.15.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '6!we3efe11p$%8x#r3y_)pioj5&-%%$g5ezmu2m_dm(^_f^2m8'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition





ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases




# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Ljubljana'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'static'),
)
SITE_ID = 1


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'templates'),],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'cms.context_processors.cms_settings'
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader'
            ],
        },
    },
]


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'djangocms_column',
    'djangocms_link',
    'cmsplugin_filer_file',
    'cmsplugin_filer_folder',
    'cmsplugin_filer_image',
    'cmsplugin_filer_utils',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_snippet',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_video',
    'mysite',
    'djangocms-css-background'

)

LANGUAGES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('en', gettext('en')),
)

CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    ## Customize this
    'default': {
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
    },
    1: [
        {
            'public': True,
            'code': 'en',
            'hide_untranslated': False,
            'name': gettext('en'),
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        },
    ],
}

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('fullwidth.html', 'Fullwidth'),
    ('sidebar_left.html', 'Sidebar Left'),
    ('sidebar_right.html', 'Sidebar Right'),
    ('template_1.html', 'Template One'),
    ('template_2.html', 'Template Two')
)

CMS_PERMISSION = True

CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'project.db',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'USER': ''
    }
}

MIGRATION_MODULES = {

}

THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.colorspace',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.autocrop',
    'filer.thumbnail_processors.scale_and_crop_with_subject_location',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.filters'
)
```

i tried

```
python manage.py makemigrations djangocms-css-background
```

and i get same error

I see in readme syntax with +. Wherever i put +, I get an error "`invalid sintax`".

I'm using django `1.10`, python `2.7`

If someone have any suggestion or other idea to do this. 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The person who has created the `djangocms-css-background` package has named the app poorly, as python does not like file names to contain a hyphen (-). They should have named the top level directory in the package as `djangocms_css_background`.

The repository and pypi package are fine to contain a hyphen, it's just the app directory.

This is why you're having problems.

That package is depreciated and no longer maintained and having a quick scan through has a few problems.

You could fork the package, resolve the problems, then install your version of the package.

But what exactly are you trying to do as I'm not overly clear from the question. If you'd like to be able to change the background colour of a  container (like this app allows you to), it's really quite simple to recreate. I'm just not 100% what you mean by the "background colour of a placeholder".

If you provide more information, I may be able to help you further.